# html+javascript: launch script on server and stream output live

Tags: jquery, html, webserver

I have a set of bash and python scripts that I would like to make run-able via a web browser.

I have an apache web server up and running on the same box that the scripts are to be run.

The optimal result would be a web page made in html+jquery from which I would select a few option then hit a button and it would run the script and show the output live as it is executed on the server.

I did some reading and did not find any simple solution. I stumbled upon websocket and other advanced stuff but I have the feeling that is a bit overkill...

I'm afraid I don't know how to phrase my need accurately so I do not find any solution

How would you implement a such thing?

Comment: most likely solution would be running a web server that serves your html front-end, and can then call the scripts based on input. Then capture the stdout and forward it on to the web browser using websockets

Comment: Ok so I should read more on websockets. I had a look over a simple python implementation and it does not seem that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server-side language such as PHP or JAVA. With the HTML front-end, the user chooses which script should be run and sends a request (using AJAX) to the server for a server-side language.

The server will run the script and the server-side language is in charge to respond the request with the results of the script.

Comment: The server-side language can be used for the response to be made ​​with websockets too.

Comment: So you would suggest websocket as the simplest solution? html/js (websocket) -> server-side (websocket) -> [python|bash]

Comment: Ajax is the simplest solution. HTML/JS ----AJAX----> server-side -> bash.
Websockets are the newer and "best" solution, but are more complex to implement.